# OpenCV how to get GLCM gray-level co-occurrence matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix, glcm

I am trying to extract features using GLCM (gray-level co-occurrence matrix (GLCM) from image) in OpenCV.

In matlab we have `graycomatrix`. Does we have any function in openCV for the same purpose? If not, then what is the best solution to achieve it and is there any working example?

[EDIT]

I tried this code but it gives wrong values as compare to matlab result any better solution/function exist in OpenCV or am I doing any mistake in GLCM process?

```
            char rawdata[4][4] = { {0, 1, 2, 3},
           {1, 1, 2, 3},
           {1, 0, 2, 0},
           {0, 0,0, 3}};

           src->imageData = (char*)(&rawdata);

             CvGLCM* glcm;
            glcm = cvCreateGLCM(src, 2, NULL,4, CV_GLCM_OPTIMIZATION_NONE);
            cvCreateGLCMDescriptors(glcm, CV_GLCMDESC_OPTIMIZATION_ALLOWDOUBLENEST);

           for (int step=0; step<4; step++)
            {
                 printf("%.3f,", cvGetGLCMDescriptor(glcm, step, CV_GLCMDESC_CONTRAST));
                  printf("\n");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class called CvGLCM:

[OpenCV-2.3.1a documentation](http://fossies.org/dox/OpenCV-2.3.1a/structCvGLCM.html)

I have never used it though.

Comment: I used this before but it does not give proper result , any idea why?

Comment: any more help??? its really important for me to solve..i have edit the question with my current code of GLCM but still correct info are not coming.

Comment: can't help you more than this, I only have an older version of opencv installed which doesn't have this package. I suggest you ask another question about the edit part of this question, people will more readily help debugging code than answer theoretical questions

Answer (score -1):

You have to install scipy,numpy,skimage. and skimage has module skimage.feature which include skimage.feature.greycomatrix and skimage.feature.greycoprops there we can calculate greycoimage for ndarray uint8 and also greco properties [instructions](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/api.html)