# Gray-Level Co-occurrence Matrices OpenCV function

Tags: c++, opencv, glcm

I am using OpenCV 2.4.11,Win 7, VS2012.
I searched the internet for glcm of an image. I found these links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875929/glcm-in-opencv2-gray-level-co-occurrence-matrices?rq=1) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383117/opencv-how-to-get-glcm-gray-level-co-occurrence-matrix?rq=1) and find out concept of glcm but my problem is remain and when run this code

```
IplImage* inputIm = cvLoadImage(filename);
IplImage* grayIm = cvCreateImage(cvSize(inputIm->width, inputIm->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);


cvCvtColor(inputIm, grayIm, CV_RGB2GRAY);
CvGLCM* glcm = cvCreateGLCM(grayIm,1,NULL,4,CV_GLCM_OPTIMIZATION_LUT);
cvCreateGLCMDescriptors(glcm, CV_GLCMDESC_OPTIMIZATION_ALLOWDOUBLENEST);
double d = cvGetGLCMDescriptor(glcm, 0, CV_GLCMDESC_HOMOGENITY );
double a = 1; double *ave = &a;
double s = 1; double *sd = &s;
cvGetGLCMDescriptorStatistics(glcm, CV_GLCMDESC_ENERGY, ave, sd);
std::cout << *ave << " " << *sd;
```

It give me this error

[image]

Note that I can write a function to do that, but limited because of memory leakage.
Can anyone help me?
regards

Comment: You linked OpenCV wrong. Also, I'd avoid using **obsolete** C syntax

Comment: It is not wrong, I create a simple project witch display image then copy these codes.OpenCV  glcm function is for c.

Comment: Have you corrected the file texture.cpp and recompiled opencv as suggested in the first link?

Comment: yes. I replaced the code of link